# How to tighten flex hose in a mini basin faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet, tools

I bought [this](https://www.victorianplumbing.co.uk/mileto-matt-black-cloakroom-mini-basin-mixer-tap-inc-click-clack-waste) faucet and I’m trying to install it. How are you supposed to tighten the hoses in the base? There 11mm nuts. I can only hand tighten and can’t find a tool to use. [image: bottom of faucet]. The bottom doesn’t come apart and the directions just say to use a spanner

Comment: There are spanners/wrenches called basin spanner/wrench, plus a few other type of wrenches for plumbing in tight spaces.  Would need to look for plumbing wrenches/tools instead of what most of us use for everyday work.

Comment: Those types of wrenches are way too big.

Answer (score 1):

We’ll I had another set of the flex hoses and some googling apparently you only hand tighten them.

[image: directions]